# Linking to a Spring MVC controller using HATEOAS when you have a composite object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

We're looking to bundle up some of our query parameters into a single object instead of keeping them separate.

I.e:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = MY_URL, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF_8)
public myMethod(@RequestParameter String user, Pagination pagination)
```

..where Pagination is a typical Java bean with getters and setters.

This works well if the Pagination class has the same fields as the query parameters. The pagination object is then instantiated and correctly populated.

The problem comes when I want to create a link using Spring HATEOAS.
I.e. this code:

```
String myHref = linkTo(methodOn(MyController.class).myMethod("johndoe", pagination)).withSelfRel().getHref();
```

The code does compile, but fails to produce links for the query parameters. We've tried using @RequestParameter as well as implemented Identifiable in the Pagination class.

Has anyone managed to create links using this pattern?

Comment: Can you post the Pagination class - not sure what it is about. Why not use the spring standard - `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` ? I usually leave the Pageable out of the link generation and just pass null when generating the link